# Gatsby. Gatsby-plugin-intl and framer motion AnimatePresence problem

Tags: gatsby, framer-motion, gatsby-plugin-intl

I need to create multilanguage site and I need to use framer motion to use animations and page transitions.

I've used the most popular gatsby plugin for multilanguage functionality [gatsby-plugin-intl](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-intl/).
To implement page transitions I've used method mentioned in this [article](https://janessagarrow.com/blog/gatsby-framer-motion-page-transitions/). I've used

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>{element}</AnimatePresence>
)
```

in **gatsby-browser.js** and then wrapped content of layout in:

```
<motion.main
    initial={{
        opacity: 0,
        x: -200,
    }}
    animate={{
        opacity: 1,
        x: 0,
    }}
    exit={{
        opacity: 0,
        x: 200,
    }}
    transition={{
        type: 'spring',
        mass: 0.35,
        stiffness: 75,
        duration: 0.3,
    }}
>
    {children}
</motion.main>
```

Without using **gatsby-plugin-intl** everything is working like it should:

[image]

But when I start to use the intl package and since I change Link component from

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
```

to

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby-plugin-intl'
```

Presence animation of framer motion stops working. There is no any animation when component unmounts.

[image]

I've searched a bit about that and found [pull request](https://github.com/wiziple/gatsby-plugin-intl/pull/138) on github. Since that time code of package was changed and the problem still exists.

Now code of intl's package Link looks like [that](https://github.com/wiziple/gatsby-plugin-intl/blob/master/src/link.js):

```
return _react.default.createElement(_gatsby.Link, (0, _extends2.default). 
({}, rest, {
  to: link,
  onClick: handleClick
}), children);
```

How to fix that?

P.S. `yarn add gatsby-plugin-intl` installs version 0.3.3. The latest version in github repo is 0.3.1. Code which is installed differs from the code in repo.

Comment: Have you tried using the native `<Link>` component? (About the routes changes and so son)

Comment: Yes, Ferran,I i've tried. When using gatsby Link animations are working, but page blinks because of the redirects that caused by intl plugin.